# Jmeter - simply way to save randomic data

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a Jmeter script that simulates 1000 devices sending random telemetry data to a server. So:

```
device1 --> himidity = ${__Random(1,100)}, temperature ${__Random(-50,50)}
device2 --> himidity = ${__Random(1,100)}, temperature ${__Random(-50,50)}
device3 --> himidity = ${__Random(1,100)}, temperature ${__Random(-50,50)}
```

....

In the next Jmeter script execution I would like generate randomic starting from the previous execution. E.g:

```
device1 --> himidity = previuos himidity + ${__Random(-5,5)}, temperature = previuos temperature + ${__Random(-5,5)}
device2 --> himidity = previuos himidity + ${__Random(-5,5)}, temperature = previuos temperature + ${__Random(-5,5)}
device3 --> himidity = previuos himidity + ${__Random(-5,5)}, temperature = previuos temperature + ${__Random(-5,5)}
```

How I can permanently save the randomic data generated in the first execution and use them in the second execution?

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the generated variables into a CSV file by:

1. Providing an additional parameters to your __Random() functions i.e.

   ```
   ${__Random(1,100,himidity)}

   ${__Random(-50,50,temperature)}
   ```
2. Using [`sample_variables` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) to save the results into .jtl results file, you will need to add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   sample_variables=himidity,temperature
   ```
3. If you want the values to be stored into a separate file, not JMeter's .jtl results file - go for [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/)
4. The values can be read from the CSV file using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
5. You can add the current random value to the previous value using [__intSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum)

   ```
   ${__intSum(${himidity},${__Random(-5,5)},)}
   ```

   [image]